# Bologna to Philadelphia - American Airlines and British Airways

Tags: british-airways, american-airlines, philadelphia, bologna

I am planning to travel from Bologna to Philadelphia. The options available are American Airlines and British Airways. I never fly with either of these two. I have heard that American Airlines has the worst services to offer. They even don't offer any food and if you want to eat something you need to pay.

Is it true?

Can anybody share the experience of American Airlines?

Does anybody know about any other good option for this route?

Comment: Seriously? I typed in [American Airlines food](https://www.google.ca/search?complete=0&&gws_rd=ssl&q=american+airlines+food) into Google, the second result is [Main Cabin food − Dining − American Airlines](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/experience/dining/main-cabin-food.jsp) which says "Meals are free on flights to and from Europe, Asia and select Latin American cities that take off during normal breakfast, lunch and dinner times." AA 729 leaves LHR at 12:05PM to arrive in PHL at 3:45PM. Looks like lunch to me. What research did you do before asking?

Comment: Any decent airfare search site will show you lots of other options.  The first one I found is Lufthansa.

Comment: I did some research and could not find any such thing. Many people even at trip advisor were mentioning that you can buy food via credit or debit card